# Is it possible to delete all Google Cloud Datastore Kinds within a namespace?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

The Datastore Admin tool allows you to delete entities in bulk by their Kind. However, when you have multiple namespaces that share Kind names, you don't seem to have a way to bulk delete entities within a Kind under a particular namespace.
Is it possible to bulk delete entities within a Kind on a given namespace? Or, if not, is there a way to bulk delete all entities within a namespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended way to bulk delete entities is Cloud Dataflow:

https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/bulk-delete

You can use a GQL query to select the entities to delete and the deletion template lets you specify the namespace to delete from:

```
--datastoreReadNamespace='mynamespace' \
```

Comment: Is it possible to specify a namespace in a GQL query?

Comment: The deletion template for Cloud Datastore let's you set the namespace to delete entities from:

--datastoreReadNamespace='' \

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Comment: Where you actually able to accomplish this ? Since by using the simple select * query you end up breaking the pipeline by reading "undeletable" kinds like __Stat_Ns_Kind_CompositeIndex__

Answer (score 2):

Its possible to bulk delete using datastore's admin tools. From the google api console navigate to your datastore instance and enable its admin tools. Once enabled you should then be able to delete entities of a given kind in bulk. Note however that you're still constrained to quota limits (for free usage), so if you need to delete more than 20,000 entities in a day then you'll probably have to pay for usage that exceeds the free quota.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to follow 
https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/bulk-delete
, then select: Bulk delete Entities in Cloud Datastore,
and under "optional parameters" fill "Read data from Datastore Namespace of"
with the namespace you wish to delete.
[image]